# How to update a form dropdown menu with PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have been trying to update my form's dropdown menu with the list of entries I have in a database. The database has been created with MYSQL. I have been looking for a solution all over, and I am not sure why, but none has worked. The latest version I have used is this:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <form method="post" action="submitRequest.php">
    Staff ID: <br>
    <input type="text" name="StfID" value="">
    <br><br>
    E-mail: <br> <input type="text" name="email" >
    <br><br>
    Select a choice:
    <br>
    <select name="Choice" value="Select" size="1"> 
    <?php
        $server= '*******';
        $user = '*******';
        $password = '*******';
        $database = '********';

    $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);

    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    } 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM choicesGiven";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
            $id=$row["ID"]; 
            $titles=$row["CTitle"];  
            $options.="<option value=\"$id">".$titles; 
    }
    $conn->close(); 
    ?> 
            <option>
            <? echo $options ?>
            </option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this, as I have been trying to access it for around a week.

I am not sure if it is better to use html file format or to create it only with php (if possible at all), thanks for any comment or help in advance.

I'm not a pro with PHP or HTML, so again, any tips / help / assistance is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Thanks to @FunkDoc and @Len_D, However, when I used either answers, didn't work. I used the main php chunk in a separate php file, and I got this error (not sure if it's of any use:

> ```
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/u309965349/public_html/Test2.php on line 11
> ```

The code in line 11 is:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die ($mysqli->error);
```

Still searching.....

Update 2: so I used the php chunk (the main chunk in the middle) and saved it as a php file. When I ran it, and echoed the $options, I got the list that I wanted, but when I use it in the html document to update the select part of the form, I still get the same $titles, which means my html syntax is not correct.

Thank you all for the help in advance.

**Update 3:**

To elaborate on the above update, I use the php chunk in a separate .php file as followed:

```
<?php
            $server= '*******';
            $user = '*******';
            $password = '*******';
            $database = '********';

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM  choicesGiven";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);  
$options;
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
{ 
        $id=$row->ID; 
        $titles=$row->CTitle;  
    //  debug_to_console ($id);
        $options.="<option value='".$id."'>".$titles."</option>"; 
}
echo $options;
$conn->close(); 
?>
```

and I managed to get the options perfectly. This is the html for adding the above code to the html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>


<form method="post" action="submitRequest.php">
Staff ID: <br>
<input type="text" name="StuID" value="">
<br><br>
E-mail: <br> <input type="text" name="email" >
<br><br>
Select a choice:
<br>
<select name="Choice" value="Select"> 
<?php

            $server= '*******';
            $user = '*******';
            $password = '*******';
            $database = '********';

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM  choiceGiven";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);  
$options;
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
{ 
        $id=$row->ID; 
        $titles=$row->CTitle;  
    //  debug_to_console ($id);
        $options.="<option value='".$id."'>".$titles."</option>"; 
}
    } 
    echo $options;
$conn->close(); 
?> 
        <? echo $options ?>
    </select>
    <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the only thing I get in the dropdown menu is This: ".$titles."

Many thanks and please let me know if you can figure this out :)

**Update 4:**

I have also tried this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
        $id=$row->ID; 
        $titles=$row->BTitle;  
    //  debug_to_console ($id);
        echo  '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$titles'</option>';

}
```

Comment: Change mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: there are several problems. the most obvious is that you are opening a mysqli connection and then using mysql. That won't work.

Comment: @FunkDoc can you elaborate? I'm relatively new to all this :) Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing mysqli and mysql commands. Edit these lines:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

To:

```
 $result =  mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   while mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Also, change this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
```

To this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will change that, but how would I be able to cycle through the rows if I'm not using the While statement?

Comment: keep the while. I just posted what needed to be changed. I updated my answer to include the while.

Comment: Thank you for that, but when I try to use that line, I get the same error as I mentioned in FunkDoc Answer.

Comment: Hi Len_D it says: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/u309965349/public_html/Test2.php on line 11. Just to clarify, the code on line 11 is the while....

Comment: You are not checking the result of the call to new mysqli. If that fails, then $conn will be null and not a valid object you can query against. Google how to make and check a mysqli connection and see if that is working first. Let me know what the result is.

Comment: Hi, so I managed to get it working in PHP, as in I managed to get the correct list echoed. But I can't get it over to html form.(I saved the php chunk as a different .php file and ran it)

Comment: How are you trying to "get it over to the html file"? Post your code please.

Comment: Hi Len_D, I updated the question with the explanation :)

Comment: OK thanks alot. I'll implement it and update you with the results:)

Comment: hi again. not success yet, no sure what the problem is, I think it's something to do with the html syntax, like the " or ' or echoing the html.

Comment: I finally ended up using a different technique altogether. Looking back, I think the problem was actually a server issue, and not the code. I did try your code somewhere else, and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

this should work. changed to mysqli across the board and fixed some html

```
<form method="post" action="submitRequest.php">
Staff ID: <br>
<input type="text" name="StfID" value="">
<br><br>
E-mail: <br> <input type="text" name="email" >
<br><br>
Select a choice:
<br>
<select name="Choice" value="Select" size="1"> 
<?php
    $server= '*******';
    $user = '*******';
    $password = '*******';
    $database = '********';

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM choicesGiven";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);  
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
{ 
        $id=$row->ID; 
        $titles=$row->CTitle;  
        $options.="<option value='".$id."'>".$titles."</option>"; 
}
$conn->close(); 
?> 

        <? echo $options ?>
    </select>
    <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I added it, but now the only thing I get as option is $titles. Not sure why though!! :S

Comment: I concatenated the $options string. Try it now with the edited code.

Comment: Thanks again FunkDoc. However, it's still showing the same text! :(

Comment: Ok, I took the php bit and created another php file to check if it's working. However, I got this: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/u309965349/public_html/Test2.php on line 11